# Get the CORE ID of a running bash script

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a script which could output the id of the core that executes the script.

I have already found a system call [**getCPU**](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/getcpu.2.html) which can achieve my goal.
However, I don't know how to call this system call and get it work in a bash script.

Any help would be grateful!

Dennis

Comment: can you add a link to the documentation on getCPU. Good luck.

Comment: A bash script only executes `builtin-commands`  (see `man bash`) as part of the bash process -- so any program you write to call getCPU will execute as a separate process forked from bash -- and the seperate process would likely run on any available core/CPU ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have taken action to pin a process to a particular core, the scheduler will move it around as it sees fit. So each time the process is scheduled it is likely to change.

On linux with a kernel >= 2.2.8 you can find the core that the process was *last run on* by looking at the `/proc/<PID>/stat` file. Eee the [PROC(5)](http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc) man page for more information. A simple awk script can be used to get the relevant information e.g. if your shell was PID 2338 then

```
awk '{print $39}' /proc/2338/stat
```

will print the CPU number that your shell last ran on. If you run the awk script several times on a multi-core/cpu system you should see the that the process moves from core to core.

If you want to set the affinity your process to a particular core (or group of cores) then you can use the [taskset](http://linux.die.net/man/1/taskset) command.

```
taskset -p 1 2338
```

will set the affinity of the process to core 0, `-p 3 2338` will set the affinity to cores 0 and 1 etc.

Comment: Another newbie question. How can I parse the output of `awk '{print $39}' /proc/2338/stat` in bash script? I have already try `read` and `new_var = 'awk '{print $39}' /proc/2338/stat'` but no luck. Any tips?

Comment: try `new_var=$(awk '{print $39}' /proc/2338/stat)`, don't forget to change 2338 to the PID of the process you are interested in too.

Answer (score -1):

```
ps -eaf | grep $$
```

This will list the parent and then use `awk` to get it